# Creating dynamically Binary Tree to Display Member In AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, binary-tree

I am using [Angular1.4.3](http://angularjs.org/) in my application.
I want to create a binary tree for displaying members in Downline. i am creating a site for MLM(Multi-Level MArketing).

In this every member have maximum two child (1 on left and 1 on right)

I search many directive through google but every directive give me vertical look. But i want to display it as horizontal somthing like this image

[image]

Comment: there is no library to build up such a thing. i think you should try to do it self.

Comment: @Asqan

yeah you are right i have to simply do infinite ng-repeat of ul and li and using css i have to do such kind of look

Comment: @Mithrandir

i have tried 
 https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview
https://github.com/wix/angular-tree-control
http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/

Comment: @GaurangGhinaiya: this looks more like the thing you want http://btv.melezinek.cz/

Comment: I think you can try d3.js tree layout:http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092

Comment: @Mithrandir How can i generate it from my json data?

Comment: @GaurangGhinaiya You might want to read the instuctions on the site.

Comment: @huanfeng its in vertical manner and i want it in horizontal manner as seen in image

Comment: @GaurangGhinaiya d3 has a transform function which can rotate it to horizontal manner.